# How to get the connected wifi network ssid?

Tags: wireless, networking, connection

I want to obtain the currently connected wifi networks ssid in a bash script. I am trying to write a backup script where the script will perform a backup to a NAS server if it's connected to my home wifi network. I have looked into the `ip route` command but it only returns some basic information -
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should provide what you are looking for assuming you are connected using 1 wireless device:

```
nmcli -t -f ssid dev wifi| cut -d\' -f2
```

Comment: it's returning all the connected networks. Can I find only the connected network?

Comment: Try it like this and let me know: nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi| cut -d\' -f2

Comment: Still returning many results

Comment: Can you pastebin what you are seeing as output?

Comment: this no longer works

Comment: @j123b567 Hi, I just had time to test this again and it works correctly. Both of them actually. Tested on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @LuisAlvarado can you please post your output of `nmcli dev wifi` and `env -i bash --noprofile --norc -c "nmcli dev wifi"`?

Comment: @j123b567 this would be the output https://imgur.com/a/ZtS6dM3

Comment: @LuisAlvarado mine is similar. So how can `|grep yes| cut -d\' -f2` works with this output?

Comment: @j123b567 yes I see what you mean, the other one is totally broken. Most likely at the moment it was working before and then after an update it broke. I will remove that one. Thank you buddy

Comment: This works for me: `nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi | grep '^yes' | cut -d: -f2 `.

Comment: @JacobEvanShreve Yes that one also works nicely. Thank you friend.

Answer (score 22):

```
iwgetid -r
```

or

```
iwgetid wlan0 -r
```

Comment: Work perfect on Ubuntu 16.0.4!!

Comment: for python `sudo iwgetid -r` works for me. (raspberry pi)

Answer (score 2):

This command returns the SSID of the connected wireless adapter (assuming you only have one).

```
iwconfig | grep ESSID | sed -e 's/.*ESSID:"\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```

It also print warning on the terminal but on stderr so it doesn't matter

```
remi@host~$id:~$ id=$(iwconfig | grep ESSID | sed -e 's/.*ESSID:"\(.*\)".*/\1/')
eth0      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
virbr0    no wireless extensions.
tap0      no wireless extensions.

remi@host:~$ echo $id
CISPI
```

Answer (score 1):

How 'bout `iwconfig wlan0 | sed -e '/ESSID/!d' -e 's/.*ESSID:"/"/'`?

Answer (score 1):

With NetworkManager-1.8.4, this produced the correct result

```
LANG=C nmcli -t -f active,ssid dev wifi | grep ^yes | cut -d: -f2-
```

There is a reason for every part of the command

- `LANG=C` is because we are using grep on localized string so force english
- `nmcli ... -f active,ssid ...` causes to print ssid with active status in form `yes:myssid` `no:otherssid`
- `grep ^yes` we want to filter active connections, but not SSIDs with text "yes" so it is the reason for `^`
- `cut ... -f2-` prints the rest of the line after the first separator so we can have SSID with separator in it

Answer (score 0):

```
nmcli -t -f NAME connection show --active
```

- `-t`       Makes the output 'terse' so no headers
- `-f NAME`  Shows only the ssid
- `--active` Shows only the active connections

Comment: This prints the NAME of connection and not the SSID. NAME usually corresponds with SSID but it is not always true. NAME of NetworkManager connection can be changed to any random value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
    iwconfig wlan0 | grep ESSID | cut -d\" -f2
```